Issue with npm shrinkwrap when installing package from custom registry
npm shrinkwrap doesn't work as expected while installing a package from a custom registry (JFrog) using npm.
When I install @zowe/cli@7.24.0 without specifying a custom registry with command npm install @zowe/cli@7.24.0, npm shrinkwrap works perfectly fine.
However, when I try to install the same package from a custom registry using the following command: npm install @zowe/cli@7.24.0 --@zowe:registry=https://zowe.jfrog.io/zowe/api/npm/npm-release/, the shrinkwrap functionality doesn't work as expected.
The signs shows that shrinkwrap was ignored:

The dependency tree is flattened inside the node_modules
The package-lock.json file does not define the "hasShrinkwrap" value

Note:

I'm using npm@10.5.1, but the same behavior was also observed in npm@9.6.7


I'm one of the developers of Zowe CLI and this is caused by a bug in npm: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4583
Third party registries like Artifactory and Verdaccio do not implement the _hasShrinkwrap flag in package metadata. In this case, the npm cli should look for the presence of an npm-shrinkwrap.json file but it doesn't and ignores it. So the only workaround I know of at this time is to install directly from the NPM registry.
